# How to order Alpha Pager by custom field?

Tags: views, 6, paging

I'm working on a D6 installation and I am trying to correct an alpha pager.

If you visit [vets-hall.org/stories/alphabetical](http://www.vets-hall.org/stories/alphabetical) you'll see I have a list of stories that have three custom fields: first_name, middle_name, last_name.

The default ordering for the view and the pager below the list goes off the last_name, that works fine.

However, if you click on one of the letters in the alpha pager above, say you click on 'M'... it orders it by the first_name field instead of the last.

I'm sure I'm missing some type of argument or something, any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Users should not be required to see an external site to be able to answer. Plus, the question needs to be valid for any future readers, not just for you; if the linked page changes, future readers will not understand your question and the given answers.

Comment: Add a screenshot of the site as you see it, and remove the link.